# how to filter "RelatedItems" column using rest api?

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom, sharepoint-rest-api

I have one RelatedItems object like :

```
var RelatedItem = "[{'ItemId':5,'WebId':'fc433b74-bae4-4548-9e6d-56062ef6da7e','ListId':'d635a608-bdf1-496c-a335-975bcb61a836'}]";

var ItemCollection = $.ajax({
  url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('"+TaskListTitle+"')/items?$Filter=RelatedItems eq "+RelatedItem,
  type: "GET",
  async: false,
  headers:{
         "accept":"application/json;odata=verbose"
  },
  dataType: "json"
});
```

This above call not working!

I want to retrieve all listitemCollection which have the same RelatedItem object in its RelatedItems field using REST API.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't filter that column like traditional columns. You can get the related item for a specific item, but you can't filter what data comes back for that specific item. Once you've retrieved the item, you can parse/filter the specific data out.